# Ajax updating database after submit

Tags: php, html, ajax

I modified the code here (http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp) to update and display my database after an input box is typed and a button is clicked to submit.
I have

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" id="processer" onsubmit="showUser('me');">
<label for="Process">Process</label><input type="text" name="process" id="process">    
<input type="submit" value="Process">
</form>
```

My Ajax code sends a:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&t=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and finally my getuser.php is

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("short", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE creator = '$q'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>data</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['data'] . "</td>
    </tr>";
      }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The problem is that when I click submit, sometimes 1 refreshes, sometimes 2 refresh, and others none at all. Like let's say i'm submitting the numbers 1 through 10, first time through I see 1, 2, then after inputting 3, i dont see anything, then suddenly 3, 4, and then nothing then 5 (while I just inputted 6), then 6, then 7, 8.

Is my php display data getting cached? or how can i make the refreshing smooth and consistent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example code is susceptible to SQL exploits. (Like pretty much all examples on w3schools. And you would find a better AJAX introduction anywhere else). -- I have no idea what you mean with 1,2,3,4,.. But instead of tedious manual xmlhttprequest setups, use jQuery which handles potential caching issues more reliably.

Comment: Thank you very much, turns out I was calling the data too quickly before it was stored into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try indexing your database so you get faster response times..